# Convert a list of strings to a Nested list of integers

Tags: python, string, nested-lists

I have this output: ['0100', '0100'] and I wanted to have something like this [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]].

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = ["0100", "0100"]

out = [[int(ch) for ch in s] for s in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Alternatively `[list(map(int, s)) for s in lst]`